# REGEX for LastName, FirstName

Tags: c#, regex

I have a function that should return True if I have a LastName, FirstName.

This name is returning False, but should return True.  Any ideas why? I want to be able to accept an apostrophe in the names, A-Z, a-z, an underscore, and 0-9.  I may or may not have a space before and after the comma.

This test name is failing: "D'Antonio, Patricia"

Code is:

```
public static bool IsName(string input)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return false;
     if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, "^\\[A-Za-z0-9_']+\\s?,\\s?\\[A-Za-z0-9_']+").Success) return true;
     return false;
    }
```

Comment: Remove ``\\`` before `[` and append a `$` at the end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why?

Comment: ``\\`` is a literal ``\`` that makes the `[` treated as a literal `[`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  And because it is c# string, I don' see any error.(other then no need to escape `[`)

Comment: It is not a problem for a C string, the regex matches something totally different then. The character class is "ruined" if a ``\\`` is used before a `[`

Comment: Do you allow a blank space between , and FirstName?

Comment: I highly recommend using the verbatim string literals when working with regex.  Use `string pattern = @"regexy stuff"` to avoid running into weird escaping problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `"^\\[A-Za-z0-9_']+\\s?,\\s?\\[A-Za-z0-9_']+"` looks like `^\[A-Za-z0-9_']+\s?,\s?\[A-Za-z0-9_']+` in literal notation, and it matches the beginning of a string (`^`) followed with a literal `[` and a literal sequence of `A-Za-z0-9_'` followed with one or more `]`, one or zero whitespace, a comma, one or zero whitespace, etc.

You need to remove the `\\` that is before `[` and add `$` at the end:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_']+\s?,\s?[A-Za-z0-9_']+$
```

Another way of writing it - use `\w` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_]` **with `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` modifier** to match only ASCII letters and digits (as [ryanyuyu suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35073162/regex-for-lastname-firstname/35073233#comment57870200_35073233)):

```
^[\w']+\s?,\s?[\w']+$
```

Note that  without the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` modifier, `\w` matches `[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_]` in .NET flavor - all Unicode letters and digits.

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%5BA-Za-z0-9_%27%5D%2B%5Cs%3F%2C%5Cs%3F%5BA-Za-z0-9_%27%5D%2B%24&i=D%27Antonio%2C%20Patricia)

The `\\` is a literal `\` that makes the regex engine treat `[` as a literal `[`. `$` is the string end anchor, so that nothing could appear after the name.

C# (use verbatim string literals, they make defining regexes easier):

```
@"^[A-Za-z0-9_']+\s?,\s?[A-Za-z0-9_']+$"
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/iRsfI8):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(IsName("D'Antonio, Patricia"));
    }
    public static bool IsName(string input)
    {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) return false;
         if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[A-Za-z0-9_']+\s?,\s?[A-Za-z0-9_']+"))
            return true;
         else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Also, if there is a chance of entering a linebreak, you might be safer with a `\p{Zs}` horizontal whitespace Unicode category class rather than `\s`.

**Further optimization:**

The previous expressions allow `','` string. To disallow them, use

```
@"^(?:\p{L}+')?\w+\s?,\s?(?:\p{L}+')?\w+$"
```

or an ASCII version:

```
@"^(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]+')?[A-Za-z0-9_]+\s?,\s?(?:[A-Za-z0-9_]+')?[A-Za-z0-9_]+$
```

Comment: This works, I just needed to accommodate for apostrophe vs single quote...  @"^[A-Za-z0-9_'’]+\s?,\s?[A-Za-z0-9_'’]+$"

Comment: You mean a curly quote, right? Yes, they can be added to expand the character classes. The only problem is adding a hyphen, ``\`` and a `]` - they should be escaped or placed in a "smart" way inside a character class. Also, a double quote must be doubled in a verbatim string literal. Just drop a comment here if you need more help with this pattern.

Comment: Worth noting, the `\w` character class includes `[A-Za-z0-9_]` already, so you could be a bit more precise by using a group like `[\w']` to just add in the apostrophe.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: No, `\w` means `[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_]` in .NET flavor - all Unicode letters and digits. I am not sure OP needs that.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my mistake.  I forget that I usually use the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option.

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of debugging, the following regex seems to work;

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[A-Za-z0-9_']+s?, s?[A-Za-z0-9_']+$")) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This pattern makes a space after a comma *obligatory*.

Answer (score 0):

```
string pattern = @"(?x) ^ [\w ']+ , [\w ']+ $ ";

Regex r = new Regex(pattern);

Console.WriteLine(r.Match("D'Antonio, Patricia")); //D'Antonio, Patricia
Console.WriteLine(r.Match("D_Antonio, Patricia")); //D_Antonio, Patricia
Console.WriteLine(r.Match("D_Antonio, Patricia01")); //D_Antonio, Patricia01
Console.WriteLine(r.Match("D-Antonio, Patricia01")); //No Match
```

- [\w'\d]+ will match any word character, hyphen and any
  digit, once or more times ( + ).
- ^ and $ will match a entire string and not parts of it.
- (?x) is a regex option that will ignore white spaces in the pattern.
  \w  allows a word character a white space and an underscore and any digit, in .Net.

Comment: 1) `\w` means `[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_]` in .NET flavor - all Unicode letters and digits. I am not sure OP needs that. 2) `\w` includes `\d` - why repeat?

Comment: *`\w` also allows a white space*  is not true. You have correctly remove whitespace from the character classes: it is not ignored in the verbose regexps.

Comment: Repeat because is the best example , the shortest, and easiest to read and understand, in my opinion.

Comment: After your last edit 2 minutes ago, your regex looks like mine, but you do not explain the nuances of using it with `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` modifier and do not provide a better alternative for a more precise check.

Comment: I had seen you r answer now, originaly you had this inplementation ^[A-Za-z0-9_']+\s?,\s?[A-Za-z0-9_']+$ , and i thought i can make it shorter, but then you added the different one similar to mine, which makes me look like i copied you which is not true, but anyway you the expert no doubt, i just new to this. I would like to ask you some advice but don'f know how start a chat away form the comments section.